# pgcrypto is not running

Tags: postgresql-9.2

I am getting error when trying to run `CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto`. The error is:

```
ERROR:  could not access file "MODULE_PATHNAME": No such file or directory

********** Error **********

ERROR: could not access file "MODULE_PATHNAME": No such file or directory
SQL state: 58P01
```

Comment: How did you install PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to install the `postgresql-contrib` package first.
If you are running on linux distrib or similar : `sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib`.

Your extensions would be located there : `/usr/share/postgresql/9.2/extension` (assuming again you're running on linux ubuntu or similar).